# No instance of constructor std::istream_iterator

Tags: c++, istream, istream-iterator

I have the following problem. I want to create a file constructor for my class. I am using `std::copy` algorithm and I get this kind of error:

```
No instance of constructor std::istream_iterator ... matches the argument list
error C2440: <function-style-cast> cannot convert from std::ifsteam to std::istream_operator
```

Here is my constructor:

```
CAirport(const char* FileName, const string& name, const int& num)
{
    m_strName = name;
    m_uNum = num;
    ifstream iStream(FileName);

    if(iStream.good())
    {
        copy(istream_iterator<CAirtravel, unsigned>(iStream),
             istream_iterator<CAirtravel, unsigned>(),
             back_inserter(m_mAirtr));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) expects `istream_type`, which is a `typedef` for `std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>`.

You are instantiating `std::istream_iterator` with `CharT = unsigned int`, which is not `std::ifstream`'s `char`. Why would you do that? Omit the second parameter altogether, let it default to `char`:

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<CAirtravel>(iStream),
          std::istream_iterator<CAirtravel>(),
          std::back_inserter(m_mAirtr));
```